# Stop a local file being used twice

Tags: javascript, security, hash

I am creating a app in javascript that runs on the users local computer, no server involved. Basically the user has a text file called score.txt that contains a highscore, to start the game the user has to upload their score.txt file and the app gets the users highscore. Now is there a way I can verify that the score.txt file hasn't been used before.

So for example I upload score.txt, I beat my score and a new score2.txt file is created, how can I stop the original score.txt from being uploaded again?

I have searched around a found I could store the hash of the files, but then what would stop the user from just deleting a hash from the log.

Is it possible to do any of this?

Comment: not sure how you would do it really, you can store data in storage that it was used, but not hard to wipe it out....

Comment: I'm a little bit confused – what would the user gain from reusing high score data?

Comment: You could write into the file the date it was used and calculate a checksum with the file-contents and a secret. Confirm that on load

Comment: strictly speaking, input/output here issue, equal input needs to produce equal output, so the logic of not being able to use the same file again is flawed, you have to modify the original file.